# URL to open a prepopulated CashApp payment w/note?

Tags: python, hyperlink, payment, deep-linking

I want to create Cashapp links for sending payments to a cashtag with a prepopulated note and amount. I know that I can do this just for a prepopulated amount using:

https://cash.app/$username/amount

does anyone know how I can add a note to this URL to include that in the prepopulation?

Comment: No, but I did find today you can generate QR codes using: https://cash.app/qr/$BrianHenryIE/10 -- but it doesn't work with "10.99". Notes would be great.